# Javascript - Is string a valid date? Date.parse doesn't catch it

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a large corpus of texts (18,000 paragraphs long), and I need to extract all of the dates from it.
Unfortunately, dates show up in many forms, and I don't want to lose any form by doing a manual rule-based regex solution that catches most but not all dates.

I started by getting all of the substrings for each paragraph, and trying to date parse them both with `Date.parse` and `moment`, but I was unlucky catching most.

Here is an example of a date I couldn't parse automatically: `7th of april 2005`

```
Date.parse("7th of april 2005")
```

> NaN

Is there an automatic way to determine if a string is a date?

Comment: Is "yesterday" a date? Is "Christmas 2005" a date? Is "the day before 7th of april 2005" a date? No, you will need to do natural language processing of the complete text to get your dates.

Comment: They are not dates in my task.

Comment: Then what is your definition of "date"? Put that into custom pattern matching engine. The rules will always be arbitrary. There is no automatic, builtin solution - you might be able to find a library that does what you need, but it'll be their custom rules then.

Comment: If you need to parse that specific format, you could do [`moment(date, "Do of MMM YYYY")`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) since `Do` is the momentjs pattern for "day of month with ordinal" and `MMM` and `YYYY` are "month name" and "year" respectively.

Comment: And as the other comments have said, this problem reduces to deciding for yourself what is a date. Is "the 17th day of the month of January in the year of our Lord 2018" a date? I can certainly identify it as a date. You may or may not want your program to identify as a date.

Comment: Don't also forget about localization issues.  For example, if you encounter the string `"01/04/12"` - is that January 4th, 2012? April 1st 2012? April 12th 2001?  Maybe it's actually 1912 or 1901?  Without context, it's near impossible to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments indicated, you have two choices:

1. Add manually all rules you think, run the script, and on error, add more rules to handle more cases. In time you will have enough rules to catch all cases.
2. Use a NLP parser, like https://github.com/wanasit/chrono or https://github.com/neilgupta/Sherlock.

This will not help if your dates are in different timezones tough. If you have some entries where the timezone is not explicit, you will need to account for that manually.

Comment: What I did was looking for the shortest substring that is a valid date with `chrono`, and that at least has all 3 parameters (day, month, year) in the text because `chrono` is tiny bit too greedy. it works.